# How to update Spark Column using an array of values in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a Dataset loaded in the memory and for every row I need to updated the value of the particular column.

I Iterate thru every row and make an API call( passing row values as parameters ) that returns me different value for every single row. I collect these values into the ArrayList.

I tried to use :

```
List<Object> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
// populate the list with values
dataframe.withColumn("c1",functions.lit(newValues));
```

but I am getting

> ```
> SparkRunTimeException : feature is not supported.
> ```

In essence what I need is to create a new Column that will contain all the values returned by my API call and then replace an existing column.

Answer (score 0):

`Lit` internally map the provided object type to its equivalent type. Since the input has type `Array[Object]` with component type as Object. Spark might not be able to map the vague object to any specific spark type. Please convert the Arraylist of Object to arraylist of String or some specific type as below-

```
List<String> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
// populate the list with values
Dataset<Row> d1 = dataframe.withColumn("c1", lit(newValues.toArray(new String[0])));
d1.show();
```

Comment: It almost there I got new dataset : 

where an array is placed in the Column,so every row contains and array 

[17, 25, 32, 39]

however I need that Column look like that :
[17]
[25]
[32]
[39]

Comment: do you need arrray of array?

Comment: No, I need a Column to contain different values : 
Row 1: 17
Row 2: 25
Row 3: 32
Row 4: 39

Comment: I was able to update the Column by creating a new Row using RowFactory.create( ... ). My last issue is to properly populate the Row with all the columns

Comment: you can use explode function then over lit